# Disable/Remove the Delete Button In The Subsonic 2.2 Scaffold Control

Tags: subsonic, scaffolding

I am working on a legacy web app that uses the Subsonic scaffold control for CRUD functionality for lookup tables. I want to give the users the ability to do everything but delete. I was not successful in my research on trying to find a simple solution like a flag or something to disable/remove this button. Is something like this available?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really see a way without changing and compiling the source from github...
Best I can see is a very hacky solution where if you set a value for the readonly columns it will prevent deletion (and unfortunately also prevent creation), but will allow editing. e.g.

```
ctrlScaffold.ReadOnlyColumns = "fdsa";
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. Unfortunately since I need to still be able to create a new record that will not work. I think I will try removing/disabling the button somehow after the form is generated.